# Switch threejs controls ( from TrackBall to FlyControls and vice versa)

Tags: javascript, three.js

What I am trying to achieve is to have two control modes, a free "flying" one, and an object-centered one (trackball) and with a button press seamlessly switch between them.

I initially tried with TrackBallControls and FlyControls. The problem with those two, is that TrackballControls is based on Euler angles, while FlyControls is based on Quartenions. I tried converting the camera.rotation vector to a quaternion by doing,

```js
quaternion.setFromEuler( target ); //where target, a Vector3 that contains degrees
```

And setting the position manually (since they use the same position object), and while it seemed to be working, rotating the camera a bit - and switching controls, started yielding horribly wrong results. Also, grabbing Euler angles from the quaternion (setEulerFromQuaternion) resulted in wrong data.

So, while I was able to switch between them, I was never able to sync their rotation coordinates, so "on switch" while the camera position is correct the rotation is wrong.

PS. I had some results with the FirstPersonControls (euler angles as well) but the screen lat,long method it is using is very error prone and fails completely when there is Z axis rotation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about something like this?

```js
function onClick() {

    var prevCamera = camera;

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(...);
    camera.position.copy( prevCamera.position );
    camera.rotation.copy( prevCamera.rotation );

    var MODE = { TRACKBALL: 0, FLY: 1 };

    switch( mode ) {

        case MODE.FLY:

            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

            mode = MODE.TRACKBALL;

            break;

        case MODE.TRACKBALL:

            controls = new THREE.FlyControls( camera );

            mode = MODE.FLY;

            break;

    }

}
```

Comment: Aaand, it works! I spent so much time fighting with rotations and quaternions and the solution was really this simple, amazing! Thanks Mr. Doob!

Comment: maybe I didn't follow the question close enough, but why is a new camera needed ? Can we not use same camera just change it's view/position/rotation with different controls ?

Answer (score 1):

Making a new camera is the easiest way to unbind all the keyboard/mouse events that were setup with the previous controls. If you don't do this you'll have orbitcontrols events fire with fly mode on.