# Switch threejs from TrackBall to Fly Control

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to change from TrackBall to Fly Controls and, although I followed the answer provided on [Switch threejs controls ( from TrackBall to FlyControls and vice versa)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304998/switch-threejs-controls-from-trackball-to-flycontrols-and-vice-versa) , I couldn't get it to work properly.

If I "rotate" the model using the trackball (by clicking on it and moving the mouse), when I switch to fly I may lose sight of the object.

My guess is that it's not enough to save the position/rotation of the previous camera, but I also need to save something else, like the world matrix position/rotation. But dunno if it's the correct way.

Example here:

http://webgl.zelda.com.br/index2.html?m=Ghirahim

http://webgl.zelda.com.br/index2.html?m=Zelda

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: TrackBall is great for Character Models (like those I posted), but it would be great to change to Fly or even FirstPerson for Room Models, like: http://webgl.zelda.com.br/?m=roomtest ... Since I have a custom GMaps ( http://maps.zelda.com.br/?map=5 ), i want to integrate these in the not so near future :)

Comment: OK. Just so you know, as of r.52, the camera controls are no longer part of the library; you have to include the code explicitly. So,... you are free to hack away. :-) Some of these controls use quaternions, others use Euler angles, and some use both.

Comment: I see, I will take a better look then. I was hoping that a "translation" from one object to another existed already :)