# three.js loaded model is disappearing while switch to FirstPerson control from Orbitcontrol

Tags: three.js

am having an option to switch Orbit control to FirstPerson control, but while switch my model is disappearing from the scene

my code is below

```
controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls( camera ); 
controls.movementSpeed = 70;
controls.lookSpeed = 0.04;
controls.noFly = true;
controls.lookVertical = false;
```

i need that switch from one control to another the object should be fixed on the position at present

Comment: This question might answer it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304998/switch-threejs-controls-from-trackball-to-flycontrols-and-vice-versa

Comment: not exactly, am saying that the object is disappearing from scene, that question is about to change from one control to another

Comment: Nothing in the code above would cause that to happen which to me suggests your camera moves somewhere where you can't see your object. Can you share a jsfiddle with the problem?

Comment: Yeah your camera is shifting ... looking at FirstPersonControls source, its onMouseMove is always active, so it may not be a suitable control for you (not without modifying it anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike OrbitControl, in the FirstPersonControl the camera points to an artbitrary directions. So use camControl.lon and camControl.lat to control the initial direction of camera.

```
camControl = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);
camControl.lookSpeed = 0.1;
camControl.movementSpeed = 4;
camControl.noFly = true;
camControl.lookVertical = true;
camControl.lon = -90;
camControl.lat = 0;
```

Also make sure your mouse is not over the window as the scene is moving because as another poster pointed out, as soon as the mouse is on the cavas FirstPersonControl will start rotating the camera.

Answer (score 0):

As of `three.js` R101, it's possible to use `FirstPersonControls.lookAt()`. `FirstPersonControls.lat` and `FirstPersonControls.lon` have been removed.

Besides, when creating `FirstPersonControls` the initial orientation of the camera is now respected.