# Switch between FlyControls and OrbitControls ThreeJS mouse clicked

Tags: javascript, three.js

i was using something similar to this: 
[Switch threejs controls ( from TrackBall to FlyControls and vice versa)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304998/switch-threejs-controls-from-trackball-to-flycontrols-and-vice-versa)

but then for switching FlyControls and OrbitControls, when i switch from fly to orbit and i click to rotate its like the controls never respond to the mouse up any more because there is no way to get it to stop rotating.

has anyone come across this before?

thanks

Comment: maybe you need to remove the click event listener

Comment: Thanks for the tip ill try that as soon as possible and let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

@wizztjh

You were right thank you very much. I fixed the issue and created a pull request. For your reference here is the link:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/7147