# React Three Fiber: How to switch between TrackballControls and OrbitControls?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to create a viewer in [react-three-fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber) with [react-three/drei](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei) where I can switch between `OrbitControls` and `TrackballControls`.
The problem is that when switching from `TrackballControls` to `OrbitControls`, the axis that the camera rotates around changes as of course the TrackballControls change the up-vector when moving around.

I created a couple of minimal examples in codesandbox to explain my approach to solve this and to show where I'm stuck.

### Base Case

This shows the initial attempt to switch between the different control types:
https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-camera-controllers-base-neu07

### Attempt #1

Obviously, this does not work as it is, so I tried resetting the up-vector to `(0, 1, 0)` and calling `lookAt()`. This seems to work initially as the camera reorients itself correctly (this is how it should look like). However, it does not rotate around the correct axis and instead moves in strange arcs. See here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-camera-controllers-set-up-vector-yps4k

### Attempt #2

For [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11309504/17572872) it was suggested to create a new camera which I also tried but ultimately it lead to the same result. This here is my attempt at creating a new camera and copying some values to the new camera:
https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-camera-controllers-reset-camera-3cih0

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of days, I finally figured out a way to achieve what I want.

Instead of trying to remove the different controls, I just enable and disable them separately. I can then call the `reset()` functions on both Controls via a ref if the control prop changes. To retain the camera position, I can just temporarily store it before resetting the controls.

You can find an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-camera-controllers-reset-camera-forked-xd6ub?file=/src/index.js).